# Storing uploaded file data with RavenDB

Tags: file-upload, attachment, cdn, ravendb

What's the current best practice for storing file data with RavenDB? (CDN or RavenDB Attachments)

I have been looking at Rob Ashton's excellent demo application [RavenDB Photo Gallery Project](https://github.com/robashton/RavenGallery). In the demo project he stores the files as RavenDB attachments but seems to mention that this is not the best practice. What is the latest thinking on this with the current version of RavenDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ken,
Attachments in RavenDB works, but they aren't meant for large files.
If you have small files, it is a workable solution

Comment: Ayende - thoughts on whether this guidance will change? We have a .NET-based desktop scientific application involving multiple large (10-100MB) binary files per dataset, with each set requiring some simple metadata. Current choices are "FILESTREAM" in EF, or just local/network path mapped by convention. A lightweight file system-based attachment implementation via RavenDB would be valuable.

Comment: The question was what is the current best practice.
The answer provided is: "this is not the best practice". It's reiterating the question, not providing an answer.